# Is 'If to do something, we should...' grammatically correct?

Tags: meaning, sentence-structure

For instance, it is correct to say that 'To avoid using more space, we should increase the running time'.

Then, is it correct to say 'If to avoid using more space, we should increase the running time'. I add 'if' to show that avoiding using more space is just a choice.

Comment: What is this about?  I don't think "If" helps, but perhaps substituting "could" for "should" would express options.  Is this about a race with 400 people, who can start at different times?

Answer (score 2):

Use "**In order**" instead of 'If," and you will see your way clearly enough.

"In order to."

Okay?

Answer (score 0):

*"To avoid using more space, we should increase the running time"* is the original sentence of the OP.

To can be replaced with "in order to" or "so as to".

1. "**In order to** avoid using more space, we should increase the running time. (This would be rather formal)
2. **So as to** avoid using more space, we should increase the running time (This is a rather uncommon)

If you place "if" then you've got to add a reason for this "if" clause.

- **If** to avoid using more space we should increase the running time **then** we must do it! (You simply create an *if..then* clause)

If you want to imply the meaning of chance then why not use *"can"* or *"may"*?

- To avoid using more space, we **can** *(may)* increase the running time.